# Removing default JavaScript files from ASP.net MVC 3 Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm just starting out with ASP.net MVC 3 and I've created an empty project. I noticed that the scripts folder is populated with a number of JavaScript files, including:

- jQuery 1.5.1
- jQuery UI 1.8.11
- Some jQuery plugins
- ASP.net MVC libraries

I want to develop my application with the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery UI served from the Google AJAX CDN. My plan is to develop a single page AJAX application, and I don't see myself using too many of the build in features for model validation, however I would like to keep the option of using it open.

Will I run into any problems with my application if I clear out the Scripts folder completely? And will I run into compatibility problems using the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery UI with the ASP.net MVC libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will I run into any problems with my application if I clear out the Scripts folder completely?

No, if you don't use them.

> And will I run into compatibility problems using the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery UI with the ASP.net MVC libraries?

No. The only compatibility problem I can think of was with jQuery UI and jQuery validate plugins but they are bot non-Microsoft so if you update them both to the latest version you won't have problems (this assumes of course that you are using client side validation, if you aren't its irrelevant to you).

So feel perfectly free to remove the scripts folder and reference external scripts from CDNs.