# Purpose of some of the JavaScript files in an ASP.NET MVC project under the Scripts folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I always see these few files under the `Scripts` directory:

```
ai.0.22.9-buildXXXXX.js
ai.0.22.9-buildXXXXX.min.js
jquery-[version #].min.map
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7716123/5531761), I can wipe out the `Scripts` folder. But I usually leave these 3 files alone, because I am afraid of bad consequences.

So What are the purposes of each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Microsoft Application Insights JavaScript SDK**

> Application Insights tells you about your app's performance and usage.
>   By adding a few lines of code to your web pages, you get data about
>   how many users you have, which pages are most popular, how fast pages
>   load, whether they throw exceptions, and more. And you can add code to
>   track more detailed user activity. ai.0.22.9-buildXXXXX.min.js can be
>   removed if you dont need to view site statics

[For more details on how to use it](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS)

**jquery-[version #].min.map**
It is used for Source Mapping

> Consider when you start debugging and you are on the particular line.
>   And you press (F11 or Click Step into Next Function Call), the
>   debugger tool will take you to jquery.min.js. And looking at jquery
>   minified version, it is impossible to find out the error.  But with
>   source maps, you can let the browser’s debugger "map" the lines in the
>   compressed file into the uncompressed source. For Source map to work
>   successfully, two things are required.
>   1. Value of sourceMappingURL exists on your server or locally.
>   2. Browser Support

[For further details](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/01/all-you-need-to-know-about-jquery-source-maps.html)

if you don't need it you can remove it

Answer (score 0):

**ai.*.js** files are for [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/). Not required and can be removed, unless if using Application Insights.

***.map** are for debugging purposes of JavaScript files. I doubt it will be necessary to debug the jQuery plugin. Not required and can be removed.